# kaite arimasu or kakimasu?

Tags: nuances, conjugations

I want to make the following sentence:

> the book has "english book" written on it

Is it

> この本は「英語の本」と**書きます**

or

> この本は「英語の本」と**書いてあります**

Comment: "This book is written: English Book" doesn't quite make sense in English...  What are you trying to say?

Comment: @ajsmart the book has 'english book' written on it,or maybe in other words 'the book has 'english book' written  on it'

Answer (score 4):

> - the book has "english book" written on it
> - ”この本は「英語の本」と書きます”　or ”この本は「英語の本」と書いてあります”

Both expressions are unnatural.

> この本には「英語の本」と書いてあります。

This expression is also inadequate. Because it is unknown where "英語の本" is written only by this expression. In other word, it is unclear whether it is written just on the cover or somewhere in the body.

On the other hand, the given sentence has "on" not "in" that implies clearly that 「英語の本」 is written on the cover of it. Also for this reason, the above expression in Japanese is inadequate.

If you hear this phrase, you will have a series of conversations like the following until you reach the conclusion.

> A: この本には「英語の本」と書いてあります。
>   B: どこに？
>   A: 表紙に。
>   B: う～ん。本の題名が「英語の本」なんだ。

I know following expressions are different from the English expression posted by the questioner, but the natural expressions in Japanese are as follows:

1. いい本があるよ。
2. どの本？　この本。
3. 何の本？　「英語の本」だよ。
4. 題名は？　「英語の本」だよ。
5. 「英語の本」って表紙に書いてあるの？　うん。
6. ということは、その本の表紙には「英語の本」って、本の名前/題名が書いてあるのか。

> 7. そうだよ。この本には表紙に「英語の本」と書いてあります。
>      （or そうだよ。この本の表紙には「英語の本」と書いてあります。）

Even after these conversations, "この本には「英語の本」と書いてあります" sounds unnatural or unconfortable.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to tell you which one is right, and a little bit of why, but if you want more detail, comment on this answer, let me know, and I will edit it.

> この本は「英語の本」と書きます。

The subject of this sentence is 本.  What about the book? Well, when we see `「英語の本」と書きます.` ~と書く can be written as `to write ~.`  Compounding this together, we get something to the effect of `The book is writing "English Book."  That's not quite right.

～と書いてある means something to the effect of `already been written.`  If you want to get a better understanding of what it means, study the [Base～て＋ある](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/grammar/sentences/?grammarid=526) grammar, and you'll get a better picture.

I'm going to make a small change to the second sentence (in bold.)

> この本**には**「英語の本」と書いてあります。
>
> "English Book" is written on this book.

In short, your second attempt was better, with minor changes.  Nicely done!

Comment: thank you for the help,is replacing the が with と still correct?,my teacher taught me to use とかいてあります

Comment: @user22630 You should be able to use と just fine.  I updated the sentence on my answer for you.

Comment: 『この本には「英語の本」 **が**書いてあります。』という文はおかしいです。『この本には「英語の本」 **と**書いてあります。/ 書かれています。』が正しいと思います。

Comment: ＠user22630  Chocolate let me know that が is incorrect, and that と is correct.  You will find that updated in my answer. :) Thanks Chocolate.